# Error signing output with public key from file 'KEY' -- File not found

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to create assembly signing in mac (version: 6.0) but I'm unable to build it successfully !

Please let me know how to fix this error.

[error display image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5k1X.png)

Comment: some package is expecting .net framework. so you need to use .net compatible version on mac

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use package "Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies" in a .NET 6.0 project. It is intended for .NET Framework 4.x projects only.

For .NET 6.0 projects package "Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client" is available.

Comment: Hey, I implemented using the "Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client", even though it was throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know assemblies (for Plugins or Custom Workflow Activities) requires .NET Framework (4.6.2 usually) and the required signing can be done only on Windows machines.

Comment: Okay, Thanks @GuidoPreite, any suggestion like which version works for implementing the plugin and assembly-signing using MACBOOK.

Comment: as I wrote "can be done only on Windows machines"